# The TextField on Paper closes unexpectedly in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In a Project, I have list of countries with its specific country codes. In order to search the countries and their codes I have created TextField on Paper(Material UI component). When clicked on it closes unexpectedly. See the code below for reference.

```
<TextField
          id="standard-select-currency"
          select
          value={countryCode}
          onChange={handleChange}
          SelectProps={{
            renderValue: (value) => value
          }}
        >
          <Paper style={{ width: "280px" }}>
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "white",
                top: "8px",
                position: "sticky",
                zIndex: "999",
                width: "inherit"
              }}
            >
              
             {/* Here this component closes when clicked on it */}
              <TextField
                placeholder="Enter Your Country"
                onChange={onChange}
                type="text"
              />

              <hr />
            </div>

            {Object.values(countryData).map((values, i) => (
              <MenuItem key={values.calling_code} value={values.calling_code}>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexWrap: "wrap",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    width: "100%",
                    position: "relative"
                  }}
                >
                  <p>{values.country}</p>
                  <p>{"+" + values.calling_code}</p>
                </div>
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Paper>
        </TextField>
```

What could be best possible solution to prevent it from shutting down?

Codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hfwb4

Comment: I know MUI `Select` is not searchable, but you should have a look at [`Autocomplete`](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete) first before trying to write your own solution.

Comment: Yes I tried Autocomplete before, but, it doesn't load countries.json and throws errors

Comment: If your main reason to switch to `Select` instead of `Autocomplete` is because of some setup errors then maybe you should ask that question first.

Answer (score 0):

just add,

```
<TextField
                placeholder="Enter Your Country"
                onChange={onChange} onClick={(event)=>event.stopPropagation()}
                type="text"
              />
it will
```

it will not close unexpectedly.

Comment: No effect... still its closing... Try in my codesandbox link

Comment: add `onClick={(event)=>event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Yes I added your code in my sandbox, but, no effect

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY it does not affect because click on the Paper component trigger   select to close. not just TextField inside

Comment: @Pranav I think you should move the searching textfield outside the select area. make it look like autocomplete. Otherwise, it still select it as an option

Comment: @VoQuocThang Yes even I was thinking the same way, but, when clicked on Select, it opens Searchbox with delay... did this before